# Is Writing a Semi Group?

Tags: group-theory, semigroups

While writing this question, I compose letters from a set $L=\{a,...z,A,...Z\}\cup\{\;\text{   } \;\}$.  **Writing** has a binary operation which is associative. The result always is an element of $L^n$.
  Does this mean that **Writing** is a [semi group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup)?

Comment: [Strings form a monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid), if that's what you're asking.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Monoids are studied in semigroup theory as they are semigroups with identity".

Comment: Minor point: for it to be a monoid you need "not writing anything" to count as writing (as otherwise you have no identity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, but as Rahul pointed out it's even a monoid. From the Wikipagepage:

> In other words, a monoid is a semigroup with an identity element. It can also be thought of as a magma with associativity and identity.

I also found this nice figure:

$\hskip0.7in$[image]